# Modifying release notes for a release using Google publishing API

Tags: android, python-3.x, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

Is it possible to modify release notes for a release? I have spent all day trying without success. This is the python code I'm using:

```
    edit_request = publishApi.edits().insert(body={},packageName=appData._packageName)
    result = edit_request.execute()
    edit_id = result['id']


    trackResponse = publishApi.edits().tracks().update(
        editId=edit_id,
        track = "production",
        packageName = appData._packageName,
        body={
            'releases':[{
                    'name':"My release name",
                    'versionCodes': ["103"],
                    "status": "draft",
                    "releaseNotes":
                    [
                        {"language": "en-US", "text": "Great release notes!"}
                    ]
            }]
        }
    ).execute()

    commit_request = publishApi.edits().commit(
        editId=edit_id, packageName=appData._packageName).execute()
```

With this code I can change the name of the release and even its state but, Release notes are not changed. I Have been reading the google api documentation and checking the samples on github but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Was this resolved? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Not for me. Vote the question to make it more visible

Comment: The probable theory which worked for me: Status needs to be completed.